# Is it possible to generate static html from Django Cms?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Hi I'm working on a project based on Django Cms 
[DJango Cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/)

Most of the templates ara generated via an APi call in ajax.. I wondered if is possible to generate an HTML static file from the original template file in order to avoid dynamic calls.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: It depends.

There's little stopping you from just creating static HTML pages (you could for example just use `wget` to crawl you website. **However** note that this only works if your content is not dynamic, as in, it doesn't depend on whether a user is logged in or not etc. If you only use plugins that always have the same output, regardless of the request, then it'll work.

Since Django CMS gives you a lot of power to write highly dynamic plugins, there's no built-in way of generating these static pages (the chances of someone using it without realizing the drawbacks are high).